# Ionic 3 not rendering variables on view change

Tags: angular, ionic3, html-rendering

So, I'm making a new app for my company's drivers, following the same patterns in the old application. The idea here is to list all the trips for the drivers and then allow them to click on one of those trips, resulting in a page with details of it.

For that I did the following simple function:

```
details(trip){
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, {
        trip: trip
    });
}
```

Then, in the DetailsPage I did the following:

html:

```
...
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Details - {{trip.TripNumber}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
...
```

details.ts:

```
...
export class DetailsPage {
  trip:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetailsPage');
    this.trip = this.navParams.get('trip');
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
  }

}
```

But when I'm clicking on the trip, I'm getting `Cannot read 'TripNumber' of undefined`, even after getting the correct trip when trying to `console.log(this.navParams.get('trip'))`...

What am I doing wrong here? I've already trying to run a zone, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Details - {{trip?.TripNumber}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

You declare `trip` as `any` so TripNumber is not available when a page loads. So you have to use `?.` for that.

Comment: Wow, I really can't believe the solution is such as simple as that. Worked like a charm

Comment: @Glad to help you.!